# Just need a simple if ... else statement to work

Tags: php

just trying to get a simple if ... else statement to work. Initially, we were given:

```
<?php
$IntVariable = 75;
($IntVariable > 100) ? $Result = '$IntVariable is
greater than 100'
: $Result = '$IntVariable is less than or equal
to 100';
echo "<p>$Result</p>";
?>
```

That needs to be turned into an if ... else statement. So far, I've written:

```
<?php
$IntVariable = 75;
if ($IntVariable > 100) {
    $Result = '$IntVariable is greater than 100';
    }
    else {
    $Result = '$IntVariable is less than or equal to 100';
    }
    else {
    echo "<p>$Result</p>";
}
?>
```

I'm really new to PHP so I may be missing something really simple...

Comment: you have two else statements.

Comment: you should use elseif if you're gonna use many else statements

Answer (score 1):

Why an `else` again to `echo $result`

if you have many conditions you can use `else if` .. otherwise give `else`

```
<?php
$IntVariable = 75;
if ($IntVariable > 100) {
    $Result = '$IntVariable is greater than 100';
    }
    else {
    $Result = '$IntVariable is less than or equal to 100';
    }
        echo "<p>$Result</p>";

?>
```